# How do I avoid having to pass my connection variable as a function parameter in a class?

Tags: php, oop, constructor, scope

I'm fairly new to OOPS PHP, and I seem to be having trouble with a basic thing.

I am attempting to set the $connection variable in the constructor, then have that variable available throughout the class without having to pass it to each function explicitly as a parameter.

The script works as expected if I pass the $connection parameter to the later function as a parameter, but it seems that the $connection variable isn't available throughout the class, as I'd think that it should be...  I get a "Undefined variable: connection" error if I don't pass it.

Any help would be appreciated.  Thanks!

```
class ClsVREQDataAccess
{

protected $connection;

public function __construct() {

    $connection = $this->ConnectToLNSODB();

    $this->InitializeNewVREQ($connection);
}


public function InitializeNewVREQ($connection) {

    ... Do stuff to set up query ...

            $rst = $connection->prepare($strSQL);
            $rst->execute($params);

    ... Do other stuff ...

}

    ... more functions, incl the above referred-to ones ...
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use `$this->connection` everywhere to refer to the object property that you assign in the constructor.

```
class ClsVREQDataAccess
{

protected $connection;

public function __construct() {

    $this->connection = $this->ConnectToLNSODB();

    $this->InitializeNewVREQ();
}


public function InitializeNewVREQ() {

    ... Do stuff to set up query ...

            $rst = $this->connection->prepare($strSQL);
            $rst->execute($params);

    ... Do other stuff ...

}
```

Comment: Hmm, that doesn't seem to do the trick.  Same error.

"Notice: Undefined variable: connection in .../Class_VREQDataAccess.php on line 107

Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Cannot access empty property in ...

Comment: What's on line 107?

Comment: $this->$connection = new PDO("sqlsrv:Server=".$serverName.";Database=DBNAME;ConnectionPooling=0", "USERNAME", "PASSWORD");

Comment: `$this->connection` not `$this->$connection`